# How to avoid "the property of undefined" error without having huge if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I usually find myself working with deep objects like this:

```
var x = {
  y: {
    z: {
      a:true
    }
  }
}
```

And somewhere in the code:

```
if( x.y.z.a === true ){
  //do something
}
```

And in some cases any of the x,y,z variables could be undefined, in which case you would get "**Cannot read property * of undefined**"

Potential solution is:

```
if( x && x.y && x.y.z && x.y.z.a === true ){
  //do something
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EcFLk/2/

But is there any easier/shorter way? Inline solutions (without using special function) would be great. Thanks.

Comment: The last one is the shortest one. For longer names, you can also use: `var tmp=x; if(tmp && (tmp=tmp.verylongname) && (tmp=tmp.evenlongernameblabla) && (tmp=tmp.doyougetit)) { ... }`.

Comment: I would want to use a special function in this case.

Comment: @Jesse can you give the example?

Comment: @shershams: FWIW, I added a couple to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, you've already found the right way. Of course, you can use a `try/catch` block and handle the error after-the-fact, but I'd use the `x && x.y && x.y.z && x.y.z.a` solution.

(You don't need the `=== true` unless you really want the condition to only be true when `a` is strictly equal to `true` and not when it's `1` or `"hi"`, but from your question, I'm thinking you know that already.)

---

You've said you don't want to use a function for this, and I haven't felt the need for one either, but just for fits and giggles:

```
function ref(obj, names) {
    var rv = obj, index;
    if (names) {
        for (index = 0; rv && index < names.length; ++index) {
            rv = rv[names[index]];
        }
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (ref(x, ["y", "z", "a"]) === true) {
    // do something
}
```

Function calls are [so cheap these days](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html)...

Or alternately:

```
function ref(obj) {
    var rv = obj, index;
    for (index = 1; rv && index < arguments.length; ++index) {
        rv = rv[arguments[index]];
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (ref(x, "y", "z", "a") === true) {
    // do something
}
```

...but on most JavaScript engines, that will be slower (`arguments` tends to be slow). But then again, you'd have to be doing it thousands of times in a loop for the speed to be an issue.

Or as Šime suggests, a single variable (I was avoiding the `split`, but it's not expensive):

```
function ref(obj, path) {
    var rv = obj, names = path.split("."), index;
    for (index = 0; rv && index < names.length; ++index) {
        rv = rv[names[index]];
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (ref(x, "y.z.a") === true) {
    // do something
}
```

[Live example of all three](http://jsbin.com/ododoc) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/ododoc/edit)

Comment: Yes, the "a" variable is just an example. Thanks

Comment: My approach would be `val( x , 'y.z.a' )` (a single string)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yeah, I was avoiding the `split`, but it's not like it's expensive. Added (and fixed a bug I thought of when I woke up this morning, and if *that's* not pathetic, I don't know what is).

Answer (score 1):

This works `:P`

```
if ( $($($(x).prop('y')).prop('z')).prop('a') ) {
    // code
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Yw5th/

It's an ugly pattern, but at least it's an one-liner and the property names don't have to be repeated (unlike `x && x.y && x.y.z && ...`).

Comment: I like it especially when you have long variable names. The only disadvantage is - you have to be careful with brackets.